# 403 Forbidden Error with Apache2

Tags: angularjs, apache, ubuntu, sublimetext2

I am trying to set up Apache2 on my Ubuntu system. It's has been installed and working. The problem is that I'm working on an AngularJS project and I need a server for my html pages. Right now the directory is set to:

```
   <Directory /var/www/html>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

When ever I try to change it to a specific path I always get the 403 Forbidden error. The path I want it changed to is:

```
/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/Quiz App
```

When the system is set to the default path and I reload my html page using Sublime Text and I get a 404 error. The html page is:

```
http://localhost/01_01/index.html
```

I've been up all night trying to fiqure this out and did the best I could to resolve it. I'm open to any possible solutions you guys may have.

Comment: Your html pages should be in /var/www/html right?

Comment: I don't know. I'm confused about the path. I couldn't find the folder.

Comment: Open terminal and run this command   cd /var/www/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Apache2 does not have permission to access path within your home directory. One thing you can do is to create a symbolic link in /var/www/html and pointing it to your code directory.

```
ln -s "/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/Quiz App" /var/www/html/quizApp
```

No open the browser and type localhost/quizApp and you should be able to open your app in the browser

Comment: Not working. I get an error
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/var/www/html/quizApp’: File exists plus I also get 403 forbidden when doing localhost/quizApp

Comment: use sudo-> sudo ln -s "/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/Quiz App" /var/www/html/quizApp

Comment: Still not working. I've changed the file name from Quiz App to quizApp, I still get the same failed to create symbolic link error.

Comment: make sure "/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/Quiz App" exists and /var/www/html/quizApp is not already present and you have permissions to write /var/www/html/ else use sudo. Make sure there is no typo in the paths

Comment: "/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/Quiz App"  is now "/home/michael/dev/JavaScript/AngularJS/quizApp"